# jQuery Number array, everything above a certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a pricing array

```
pricing = new Array();

pricing[1] = 35;
pricing[2] = 60;
pricing[3] = 84;
pricing[4] = 104;
pricing[5] = 120;
pricing[6] = 132;
pricing[7] = 140;
pricing[8] = 144;
pricing[9] = 153;
pricing[10] = 160;
```

Everything below 10 has a price, everything above 10 will have the same price as ten

It only goes to 20 so what i did originally was just repeat the price for 11 - 20. But thats wasteful, how can I tell me array that everything > 10 = 160

p.s my final version of this is condensed :)

Comment: are you saying that when accessing pricing[11], it should return 160??  like alert(pricing[11]); should alert 160??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pricing = [], i;
pricing.push(35);
pricing.push(60);
pricing.push(84);
pricing.push(104);
pricing.push(120);
pricing.push(132);
pricing.push(140);
pricing.push(144);
pricing.push(153);
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    pricing.push(160);
}
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38Erq/1/) for this.

@CD was stating that the [push function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) can take multiple items to append to the array.  The code would look like this then:

```
var pricing = [], value = 160;
pricing.push(35);
pricing.push(60);
pricing.push(84);
pricing.push(104);
pricing.push(120);
pricing.push(132);
pricing.push(140);
pricing.push(144);
pricing.push(153);
pricing.push(value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value);
```

Comment: You can pass the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function more then one element: `array.push(element1, ..., elementN)`

Comment: Well aware of that, you could store 160 in a variable and then just pass that in 11 times in the push call but six in one and a half dozen of the other

Answer (score 2):

You can leave your array as is and use a function like:

```
var getPrice = function(arr, index){
    return arr[index > 10 ? 10 : index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=10;
while(i--) { pricing[i+10] = 160; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pricing = new Array();
var arraySize = 100;

pricing[1] = 35;
pricing[2] = 60;
pricing[3] = 84;
pricing[4] = 104;
pricing[5] = 120;
pricing[6] = 132;
pricing[7] = 140;
pricing[8] = 144;
pricing[9] = 153;

for(var x = 10; x < arraySize; x++)
    pricing[x] = 160

console.log(pricing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the first entry in your array (since it is 0 based). I would change it to this:

```
pricing = new Array(20);

pricing[0] = 35;
pricing[1] = 60;
pricing[2] = 84;
pricing[3] = 104;
pricing[4] = 120;
pricing[5] = 132;
pricing[6] = 140;
pricing[7] = 144;
pricing[8] = 153;
pricing[9] = 160;
```

Then you can set the last 10 using this:

```
for(var x = 10; x < pricing.length; x++) {
    pricing[x] = pricing[9];
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwAga/).